# Adding path link in translated content with Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

For my lage information pages the content is generated from a translation xlf file as raw text.

Here is part of the xlf file:

```
<target><![CDATA[Click <a href="{{ path('_homepage') }}">here</a> to go to the homepage]]></target>
```

This is added with the following twig code:

```
{{ content|raw|nl2br }}
```

Only the path url to the homepage is not working as it is put as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add link separately, eg:

`<target><![CDATA[Click {link} to go to the homepage]]></target>`

Comment: Is it best to translate the place holder with a str_replace in the controller or send the link as variable to twig and translate the placeholder as %link% placeholder?

Comment: There's no need to use str_replace - just inject Translator service and let it do its best.